# Swift passing self as argument in class init

Tags: swift, class, init, self

I have a "User" class in my Swift project. Because of the vast functionality this class must provide, I want to delegate tasks to other classes stored in the User class as instance variables. For instance, each user will have an instance of the "Feed Manager" class stored in it as an instance variable.

This can be done in other languages (I built it in Python first) but I don't know if this is possible in swift. Specifically, I need to pass the User self into the Feed Manager instance in the User init (to uniquely link the instances) but Swift is throwing "self user before all stored properties are initialized". Any way to get around this and achieve the desired functionality?

Code:

```
class User: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let feeds: FeedManager
    var username: String
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var fullname: String
    var bio: String
    
    init(username: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, fullname: String, bio: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.fullname = firstname + " " + lastname
        self.bio = bio
        
        self.feeds = FeedManager(user: self)
        
    }
    static func == (user1: User, user2: User) -> Bool {
        return user1.id == user2.id
    }
    
}

class FeedManager {
    let user: User
    var currentInvit:       [PostData] = []
    var currentHost:        [PostData] = []
    var currentAttend:      [PostData] = []
    var currentDismissed:   [PostData] = []
    var pastHost:           [PostData] = []
    var pastAttend:         [PostData] = []
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have a `lazy var` to do so. `lazy var feeds: FeedsManager = { FeedManager(user: self) }()`? But since it might be unclear what you want to do with `FeedManager`, the architecture might be different.

Comment: If FeedManager is a property in User then it doesn’t need a User as a property, removing this double coupling would improve the architecture. Off topic: fullName is a parameter in your init method but you don’t use it

Comment: yeah I noticed the full name thing haha

Comment: I need self in the Feed manager because some of the methods in the feed manager need to reference data stored in the User object (or other objects I might store in User as instance variables)

Comment: How does a lazy var fix the problem? I've never used lazy before

Comment: Then remove the other coupling, FeedManager as a property in User.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Also note that `User` and `FeedManager` form a strong reference cycle (an ownership cycle), that is, a memory leak.

Comment: I don't lose any functionality by putting everything just in the User class, though it would be massive and not subdivided in the intuitive way

Comment: I mean that User should not have a property FeedManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lazy var approach, have `feeds` be an optional or declare it as an implicitly-unwrapped optional. You initialize all stored properties and then set the `FeedManager` initializing it with self.

```swift
class User {
    let id = UUID()
    var feeds: FeedManager!   // implicitly unwrapped
    //var feeds: FeedManager?
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        feeds = FeedManager(user: self)
    }
}

class FeedManager {
    weak var user: User?
    var currentInvit: [String] = []
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
    }
}
```