# Passing self into initializer as delegate within own initializer

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

might be a silly question, but I'm trying to understand better why I can't do this. I recall this working in Swift 5.6.1, but I recently updated to Swift 5.7.2.

Before asking, I want to note that I did see this question: [Swift passing self as argument in class init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835851/swift-passing-self-as-argument-in-class-init), but it didn't quite answer my question. Or maybe I just want to see if these are the only solutions...

I have a couple of classes that's something like this.

```
class Bar {
    weak var delegate: FooDelegate?

    init(delegate: FooDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}

class Foo: FooDelegate {
    var bar: Bar

    init() {
        self.bar = Bar(delegate: self)
    }
}
```

Before I updated, I don't remember this throwing any errors. Now I'm getting the error
`Variable 'self.bar' used before being initialized`.

Is there a way to set this up so that I'm passing the delegate correctly?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by breaking it up in two steps, create the `Bar` object and  then set `delegate`

```
init() {
    bar = Bar()
    bar.delegate = self
}
```

Of course this requires a new `init` for the `Bar` class

Comment: Easy enough to do, but why should it have to be done this way? Why doesn't initializing with self work?

Comment: Isn't this simply because the init passes `self` to `Bar(delegate:)` and _then_ it assigns the returned object to `self.bar`, so the `self` passed to the Bar init is "under construction" so to speak but in my solution `self` has been completely initialised before it is used.

Comment: Well, I'm not a huge fan of this solution either, but it's more than I had before. For that, I'm very grateful, thank you.

Comment: I never said it was pretty :). I agree that sometimes when writing inits this situation will force me to write the code in a way I don't want to.